# What pattern should I use for merging data display tables

Tags: usability, design-patterns, design

I have a situation where i'm splitting one huge table (it is beyond 3 folds of screen) and creating two tables (one is new and other is updated version of old)

Which are again huge in terms of height. Shall I show 2 tables one by one vertically (I'm not in favor of it) or in [tabs](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/ModuleTabs) format with following names:
1: Updated
2: Newly created

Or is there any other way to represent the data?

Comment: Please be more clear about what you are asking. Where did the new table come from? Is it some iteration of the old one? What are these tables? What data they contain?

Comment: +1 to BlueFlame, Adding to his questions - Are both the tables similar (same columns / order etc.). Basically, is the new table a subset of the parent table?

Comment: Do your users need to compare data between the two tables? If they do, don't put them in tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that the new table is a subset of the parent table, One way to go would be to provide a toggle view of the Table.

So e.g. assume that you have a huge table and there is some data that you want to select and tag as "Flagged"
So steps would be:

1. Select Rows
2. Mark as "Flagged"
3. Switch to Toggle View "Flagged" to view at all rows that have been flagged

Typically, this will NOT remove rows from parent table. So you modify step 2 and say

- New 2) Mark as "Flagged" and Remove

Now, when you switch to the Toggle View you have the rows that have been removed from the Parent table.

If you can share a sample that will help tailor the answer.